# Rails sum with group by and include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to make some calculations over my models, but the generated sql is just not working.

I have this models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :order_date
  has_many :order_products, dependent: :destroy

class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount
  belongs_to :tariff
  belongs_to :order_product_format
  belongs_to :product

class OrderProductFormat < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount

class Tariff < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price
```

So I created a function in my Order controller to get the total amount of all the orders as follows

```
def self.global_total_amount
  OrderProduct.joins(:order_product_format, :tariff).sum '((order_products.amount * order_product_formats.amount ) * tariffs.price)'
end
```

This works as expected, but now I want to group this total amounts by month of the year, so I'm trying to do something like this

```
def self.month_total_amount
  OrderProduct.includes(:order).joins(:order_product_format, :tariff, :order).group('"order"."order_date"').sum('((order_products.amount * order_product_formats.amount ) * tariffs.price)')
end
```

And I get the following error:

```
SELECT SUM(((order_products.amount * order_product_formats.amount ) * tariffs.price)) AS                     sum_order_products_amount_all_order_product_formats_amount_all_, "order"."order_date" AS order_order_date FROM "order_products" INNER JOIN "order_product_formats" ON "order_product_formats"."id" = "order_products"."order_product_format_id" INNER JOIN "tariffs" ON "tariffs"."id" = "order_products"."tariff_id" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "order_products"."order_id" GROUP BY "order"."order_date"

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "order"
LINE 1: ...cts_amount_all_order_product_formats_amount_all_, "order"."o...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach to do this?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
def self.month_total_amount
  OrderProduct.includes(:order).joins(:order_product_format, :tariff, :order).group('orders.order_date').sum('((order_products.amount * order_product_formats.amount ) * tariffs.price)')
end
```

You seem to have named your orders table wrong. You don't enclose the table and field in quotes.

So like this  = `group('orders.order_date')`

not like this = `group('"order"."order_date"')`